# I want to change the theme based on value getting from sensor manager . But i don't know the range of it .

Tags: android, range, sensormanager, light-sensor

```
@Override
   public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT){
     textLIGHT_reading.setText("LIGHT: " + event.values[0]);
    }
   }
```

Here i am getting 100 .Value will change based on the surrounding .
I want to change the theme based on the value getting from sensor .
Like for night i want dark theme and for day  i want light theme . 
What is range for dark ? in sensor

Answer (score 0):

```
if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT){
 setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Light);
 recreate();
 textLIGHT_reading.setText("LIGHT: " + event.values[0]);
} 
else {
   setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dark);   
   recreate();
}
```

Try the above solution !!

Comment: so if it's dark !   event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT   will be false

Comment: else part is handling that !! @vinaymishra ..yaa.. if its not light then every case it will be dark.. or any other cases which is not related to light !!